# Why does my SQL 'INSERT' statement execute twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have the following Insert Command and I need to grab the Scope Identity for some order tracking later in the application

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [pharm_OrderID](UserID, RequestType, CreateDate) values (@UserID, @RequestType, @CreateDate); Select SCOPE_IDENTITY();", conn1);
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    conn1.Open();

                    string strUserID = txtEmpID.Text;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                    cmd1.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = strUserID;

                    string strRequestType = ddlReturnType.SelectedValue;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@RequestType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                    cmd1.Parameters["@RequestType"].Value = strRequestType;

                    string strCreateDate = lblOrderAttemptTime.Text;
                    cmd1.Parameters.Add("@CreateDate", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
                    cmd1.Parameters["@CreateDate"].Value = strCreateDate;

                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    string numScope = Convert.ToString(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
                    lblOrderNum.Text = numScope;
                    cmd1.Dispose();
                    conn1.Close();
                    conn1.Dispose();
```

But why does it insert twice?

Comment: Tip: You may want to look into the `using` statement for handling the connection and command instances.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are executing it twice

1. `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();`
2. `Convert.ToString(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());`

You just need `ExecuteScalar` to insert and select:

```
decimal newID = (decimal) cmd1.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you've executed it twice; once as ExecuteNonQuery() and once as ExecuteScalar().

Answer (score 2):

because you are executing it twice:

```
   cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); //once

   string numScope = Convert.ToString(cmd1.ExecuteScalar()); //twice
```

Get rid of `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();` and just use the `ExecuteScalar()`.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your query executes twice is because you are calling both ExecuteNonQuery
and ExecuteScalar on your command object.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are executing it twice.

First here:

```
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Then here:

```
string numScope = Convert.ToString(cmd1.ExecuteScalar());
```

Remove the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing it twice.

```
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery(); // 1st

string numScope = Convert.ToString(cmd1.ExecuteScalar()); // 2nd
```

Delete one of these.